# How can I obtain the current GPS location?

Tags: java, android, gps

I am about to build an app in Android that will act as a clock-in card for employees on the road.

At the start of a job the user will click a button that will record the GPS location and current time (thus verifying that he is where he should be at a given time) and again at the end of the job he records the time and GPS location.

SO I reckon this will be easy enough, except that I can't find a way of pulling current location data. The nearest I can find is `onLocationChanged` which implies that I cannot get a stationary GPS read. I know it has to be possible to do this but cannot find a working example of how it would be achieved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a bit of research this is what I came up with:

```
public class UseGps extends Activity
{
    Button gps_button;
    TextView gps_text;
    LocationManager mlocManager;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        gps_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.GPSButton);
        gps_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.GPSText);

        gps_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View viewParam) {
                gps_text.append("\n\nSearching for current location. Please hold...");
                gps_button.setEnabled(false);
                mlocManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
                LocationListener mlocListener = new MyLocationListener();
                mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mlocListener);
            }
        });
    }

    /* Class My Location Listener */
    public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener
    {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location loc)
        {
            double lon = loc.getLatitude();
            double lat = loc.getLongitude();
            gps_text.append("\nLongitude: "+lon+" - Latitude: "+lat);
            UseGps.this.mlocManager.removeUpdates(this);
            gps_button.setEnabled(true);
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    }
}
```

This sets up an activity with a button and textview. Set a listener on the button which starts the location manager.

I have set up a class, `MyLocationListener`, which implements `LocationListener`, and then I override the `onLocationChanged()` method, basically telling it that the first location it gets it appends to the textview and then it removes the location manager.

Thanks to those who helped and I hope this is of use to someone else.

Answer (score 1):

You should try to [**`android.location.LocationManager.getLastKnownLocation`**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#getLastKnownLocation(java.lang.String))

And check the time of the returned Location using `Location.getTime(utc time)`.

Comment: ok, and excuse my ignorance, but lastKnownLocation dosnt imply my current location at this time.. I want the app to go get my location as soon as I press the button, is it not possible that the last known location happened a half hour ago 2 miles back the road?

Comment: then onLocationChanged is the best way to get the most up-to-date position.

Comment: But thats my point, what if I am stationary and want to get the position that I am currently at? Is there a way of initialising my location to , say , 0 0, which would then trigger a location change?

Answer (score 0):

Request location updates and create a LocationListener (see `LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates`). You will receive regular updates with information about accuracy.

Until you get your first update, you can (as posted) use `LocationManager.getLastLocation()` and check its timestamp and accuracy.

Word of warning - some devices scan take forever to get you an accurate reading, and it's completely random.

Comment: ok, so I so something like this then.. click the start button and and get a timestamp, and basically keep polling the lastKnown loaction untill I get a location with a timestamp greater than my starting timestamp.. 

I must say, I cant believe there isnt a way of doing an in the spot check. The device I am using is pretty quick at getting my location when I use google maps or the navigator...

Comment: Don't poll lastKnown! Look at last known once and request updates as shown above. If it changes, you'll be notified. If it doesn't change, then lastKnown won't change either!

Comment: Ok, I really dont want to appear lazy, but I learn best by example, so on that note is there any way you (or anyone) can post some sample code?